# Accessing longitude, latitude outside the geocode() function

Tags: google-maps

```
function fillInAddress() {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latitude;
var longitude;
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': place.formatted_address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                     latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                     longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                } else {
                    alert("Request failed.")
                }
            });

 document.getElementById("long").value = longitude;
document.getElementById("lat").value = latitude;
}
```

I cant access latitude and longitude outside geocode() function. Please help.

Comment: You can set element values inside `geocode()` success part.

Comment: @AntoJurković..thanks for the reference..it works for me